# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage',

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Full error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

I'm trying to get some data from web api with viewmodel.

This is my action

```
public ActionResult PayBilgileri()
    {
        Session["dersGrupID"] = 470122;
        int DersGrupID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["dersGrupID"]);

        Core.ViewModel.Ders.DersDetay.PayVeNotBilgileriViewModel PayBilgileri = new Core.ViewModel.Ders.DersDetay.PayVeNotBilgileriViewModel();

        PayBilgileri.DersPlanID = DersGrupID;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myapi.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            //HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Ders/ListelePaylarVeNotBilgileri").Result;
            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Ders/ListelePaylarVeNotBilgileri", PayBilgileri).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
            return PartialView(response);
            // PartialViewResult(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

And the partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<Core.ViewModel.Ders.DersDetay.PayVeNotBilgileriViewModel>

<table class="table">

@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
   <tr>
      <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KatkiOrani)
      </td>
   </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear: you're passing the HttpResponseMessage object you get back from PostAsJsonAsync() directly to your partial view, but your partial view expects its model to be of type IEnumerable<>

Comment: I got it but i don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extract the data from the `HttpResponseMessage` as `IEnumerable<PayVeNotBilgileriViewModel>` and only then pass it as the view-model:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var vm = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<PayVeNotBilgileriViewModel>>().Result;
    return PartialView(vm);
}
```

See [ReadAsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontentextensions.readasasync%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)